# Insert POST data to table and POST array to seperate table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to submit data from a form to two separate tables.

**Here's the error:** It inserts into table 1 fine but table2 array data goes into the database as "**Array**".

Here are my fields going into table1:

```
  $start = $_POST['start'];
  $end = $_POST['end'];
  $customer = $_POST['customer'];
  $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
  $rep = $_POST['rep'];
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];
```

My array fields going into table2:

```
  item[]
  description[]
  pack[]
```

Any help is appreciated. Below is the code I have developed thus far:

```
 if ($start == '' || $end == '')
                    {
                            $error = '<div class="alert alert-error">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                <strong>Error!</strong> Please fill in all required fields!
            </div>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) + 1 AS newGroupID FROM table1";
try 
    { 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

foreach($rows as $row) {
$groupID = $row['newGroupID'];
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "mydb");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }


  $start = $_POST['start'];
  $end = $_POST['end'];
  $customer = $_POST['customer'];
  $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
  $rep = $_POST['rep'];
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT table1 (GroupID, start, end, customer, manufacturer, rep, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("issssss", $groupID, $start, $end, $customer, $manufacturer, $rep, $notes);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement 1.";
                            }


                            $mysqli->error;
                            $mysqli->close();
                            $success = "<div class='alert alert-success'>New agreement added.</div>";



                            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "mydb");
                            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                die(mysqli_connect_error());
                            }

                            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT table2 (GroupID, item_number, item_description, pack) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    foreach($_POST['item'] as $i => $item) {
                                        $item = $_POST['item'];
                                        $description = $_POST['description'];
                                        $pack = $_POST['pack'];
                                    }

                                    $stmt->bind_param("isss", $GroupID, $item, $description, $pack);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement 2.";
                            }


                            $mysqli->error;
                            $mysqli->close();
                            $success = "<div class='alert alert-success'>New agreement items added!</div>";


            }
            }
```

Comment: what is not working? are you getting any error message ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Just updated my post (see top). Table1 inserts fine but table2 array data inserts as "Array" rather than the actual data.

Comment: Are you using both `PDO` (1 connection) AND `mysqli` (2 separate connections)

Comment: an addition to what @Sean mentioned, your bind_param, execute and close function calls should be inside the corresponding foreach loops for item array.

Comment: Also, if description and pack are arrays, then I don't think this is the right way to do it: $description = $_POST['description'];
                                        $pack = $_POST['pack'];

Comment: @Maximus2012 What would be the correct way to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

UPDATE:
Since OP's original code does not give correct value for $GroupID, this is one way to resolve that: (this is based on the assumption that OP needs different values for GroupID for each insert queries)

```
$GroupID_arr = Array();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $GroupID_arr[] = $row['newGroupID'];
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into table2 (GroupID, item_number, item_description, pack) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")){
    foreach($_POST['item'] as $i => $item) {
        // since item, description and pack are multi-dimensional arrays,
        // this is how you reference them
        $item = $_POST['item'][$i];
        $description = $_POST['description'][$i];
        $pack = $_POST['pack'][$i];
        $GroupID = $GroupID_arr[$i];
        $stmt->bind_param("isss", $GroupID, $item, $description, $pack);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement 2.";
}
```

This is for a specific part of your code. If this does not work then there might be errors in some other parts of your code. <del>Also, looking at other parts of your code, I see that the value for $GroupID that you will get is not correct since your are overriding the value in the foreach loop.</del>

Comment: is item_number integer or string? Also look at the update that I made regarding the value for $GroupID.

Comment: I used your updated code and removed GroupID and it inserts successfully - so GroupID appears to be the problem. Do you think getting the most recent inserted ID for that column in the previous query would be a better solution?

Comment: it could be but you'll have to make changes to your code to either make this all part of one foreach loop or store the GroupID value returned from the previous query into an array.

Comment: How would I go about storing the GroupID value into the array?

Comment: see if the updated solution helps. As I mentioned before, there might be some other parts of the code that are breaking your logic.

Comment: That solution is for the case when you want to have different values for GroupID for each of your insert queries. If you want same values then earlier solution should work.

Comment: If you've set up GroupID as primary key for table2 and you try to insert non-unique values for GroupID then that would be a problem which is what I think is happening here.

Comment: I selected the last inserted group ID via a separate query and just inserted that instead. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.